# Is the following proposition, "If $x < y$, then $x \leq y$" true or false?

Tags: inequality, logic

I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere, but I've run across this problem in proving inequalities a lot, and I haven't been able to find an answer so I would like to ask if the proposition is true. I feel like it is, but I'm not certain because I can't recall a time I've actually seen it used in a proof. When we say $x \leq y$, we say "$x$ is less than OR equal to $y$," so if we know $x < y$, is it enough to conclude that $x \leq y$, since one of the cases is always satisfied? Maybe the more general question is, if we ask the question is "$x, y$ or $z$", and we know it's one of them but not the other, is it enough to conclude $x$ is $y$ or $z$, if it's one but never the other?

Comment: $P\implies P\vee Q$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed, since $x\leq y$ cannot be false when $x<y$ is true, therefore the conditional, $(x<y) \to (x\leq y)$, is held to be true.

If $x$ *is* less than $y$, then $x$ is *less than or equal to* $y$.

---

Essentially, $\rm P\to(P\vee Q)$ is a tautology.   A disjunction is true *when* at least one of its disjuncts is true.   So if a preposition is true, then its disjunction with something else is true.

> I feel like it is, but I'm not certain because I can't recall a time I've actually seen it used in a proof.

I'm quite sure you have, in some form or other.   The rule of inference known as *weakening*, or *disjunction introduction*, is used quite frequently.

Well, okay, here the disjunction is *hidden* inside the definition for $\leq$.   But you still realised it was there.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation :)